# multipass shadow mapping renderer in XNA

Tags: xna, lighting, shadow-mapping

I am wanting to implement a multipass renderer in XNA (additive blending combines the contributions from each light).  I have the renderer working without any shadows, but when I try to add shadow mapping support I run into an issue with switching render targets to draw the shadow maps.  When I switch render targets, I lose the contents of the backbuffer which ruins the whole additive blending idea.

For example:

```
Draw()
{
    DrawAmbientLighting()
    foreach (DirectionalLight)
    {
        DrawDirectionalShadowMap() // <-- I lose all previous lighting contributions when I switch to the shadow map render target here
        DrawDirectionalLighting()
    }
}
```

Is there any way around my issue?  (I could render all the shadow maps first, but then I have to make and hold onto a render target for each light that casts a shadow--is this the only way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XNA, setting a a render target (including the backbuffer) clears it. This is because preserving the contents of the buffer requires a slow copy operation on the Xbox 360. The PC version just uses the same behaviour to make porting easier.

You can override this behaviour by passing `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents` to the constructor of `RenderTarget2D`.

To set it on the backbuffer, respond to `PreparingDeviceSettings` and modify `GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.RenderTargetUsage`.

If it's possible, without requiring more targets or draw operations (and it usually is), it's better to re-order your draw function so you don't have to re-set targets you've already rendered to.

More info in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919060328/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).